# Send message to azure service bus with properties

Tags: powershell, azureservicebus

I am using the following powershell code to send a message to an Azure Service Bus Topic with a property set:

```
function Send-AzServiceBusMessage {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $ResourceGroupName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $NamespaceName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $TopicName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string] $PolicyName = 'RootManageSharedAccessKey',
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string] $Property1
    )
      
    $message = [PSCustomObject] @{ "Body" = "Test message"; "Property1" = $Property1 }        
    $namespace = (Get-AzServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $namespacename).Name
    $key = (Get-AzServiceBusKey -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Namespace $namespacename -Name $PolicyName).PrimaryKey
    $message.psobject.properties.Remove("Body")
    $token = New-AzServiceBusSasToken -Namespace $namespace -Policy $PolicyName -Key $Key
    
    #set up the parameters for the Invoke-WebRequest
    $headers = @{ "Authorization" = "$token"; "Content-Type" = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8" }
    $uri = "https://$namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$TopicName/messages"
    $headers.Add("BrokerProperties", $(ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Message -Compress))
        $result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Method Post -Body $body 
    if ($result.StatusCode -ne 201) {
        $result
    }
```

I have a rule set up on a topic subscription such that:
Property1 in ('somevalue')

However, if I set up a catch all subscription with no rules, I can see the message is being received by that and not by the subscription with the rule. So my question is how do I send messages with properties set using powershell. Similar to this in C#:

```
            var message = new BrokeredMessage { MessageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()};
            message.Properties["Property1"] = "somevalue";
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.properties?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_BrokeredMessage_Properties) it looks like you have to nest your custom properties in a `Properties` member:

```
$headers.Add("BrokerProperties", $(ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @{ Properties = $message } -Compress))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as above with the following modifications:

```
$message = [PSCustomObject] @{ "Body" = "Test message" }
$headers = @{ "Authorization" = "$token"; "Content-Type" = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"; "Property1" = $Property1  }
$headers.Add("BrokerProperties", $(ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $Message -Compress))
```